# Does We3.toWei function accept decimal number?

Tags: ethereum, truffle, web3js

I am doing some research about Web3js.

I try to build one contract that can let anyone to purchase my token by ether.

I use testrpc to build my pricate chain

Here is my transfer function

```
 handleTransfer: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var amount = parseInt($('#TTTransferAmount').val()); // get the ether amout

      console.log('Pay ' + amount + ' ether');

      var GustavoCoinCrowdsaleInstance;

      web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }

        var account = accounts[0];

        App.contracts.GustavoCoinCrowdsale.deployed().then(function(instance) {
          GustavoCoinCrowdsaleInstance = instance;
          console.log(typeof amount );
          console.log( web3.toWei(amount, "ether"));
          return GustavoCoinCrowdsaleInstance.sendTransaction({ from: account, value: web3.toWei(amount, "ether")})

        }).then(function(result) {
          alert('Pay Successful!');
          $('#TTTransferAmount').val(0);
          return App.getBalances();

        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err.message);
        });
      });
  }
```

I try to use web3.toWei function to converts an ethereum unit into wei

when I type console.log(web3.toWei(1,'ether'));
The result is fine,it will return `1000000000000000000`

but when I type console.log(web3.toWei(0.1,'ether')); 
it will return `0`

Does toWei function only accept integer?

What should I need to do if I want to use 0.1 ether to purchase token?

Comment: `web3.toWei(0.1, 'ether')` returns `"100000000000000000"` for me. What version of `web3.js` are you using?

Comment: Hi, the problem fixed. My bad, I used parseInt function before run web3.toWei. So I will always get 0 when I set 0.1 into amount.